# Appointment cancellation through ics file in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, icalendar

I am trying to create an appointment through ics file and it's working fine but when i create another ics file for cancellation of appointment and try to import, it throw's 
error "Couldn't open event, it's possible the calendar file is corrupted".

For appointment creation APPOINTMENT.ics creates entry as expected

APPOINTMENT.ics

```
 BEGIN:VCALENDAR
 PRODID:-//Lotus Development Corporation//NONSGML Notes 9.0.1//EN_C
 VERSION:2.0
 BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
 TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
 BEGIN:STANDARD
 DTSTART:19501029T020000
 TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
 TZOFFSETTO:+0100
 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
 END:STANDARD
 BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
 DTSTART:19500326T020000
 TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
 TZOFFSETTO:+0200
 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
 END:DAYLIGHT
 END:VTIMEZONE
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 UID:123456
 ORGANIZER;CN=Avi Kaushik/Show:mailto:CN=akaushik@xyz.de
 DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20190410T130000
 DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20190410T140000
 LOCATION:
 SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:process ics file 555555
 DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:  \n
 TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
 TRANSP:OPAQUE
 END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR
```

but when try to cancel above entry through CANCELLATION.ics which contains same UID as APPOINTMENT.ics ,it doesn't work

CANCELLATION.ics

```
 BEGIN:VCALENDAR
 PRODID:-//Lotus Development Corporation//NONSGML Notes 9.0.1//EN_C
 VERSION:2.0
 METHOD:CANCEL
 BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
 TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
 BEGIN:STANDARD
 DTSTART:19501029T020000
 TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
 TZOFFSETTO:+0100
 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
 END:STANDARD
 BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
 DTSTART:19500326T020000
 TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
 TZOFFSETTO:+0200
 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
 END:DAYLIGHT
 END:VTIMEZONE
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 UID:123456
 ORGANIZER;CN=Avi Kaushik/Show:mailto:CN=akaushik@xyz.de
 DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20190410T130000
 DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20190410T140000
 SEQUENCE:1
 STATUS:CANCELLED
 LOCATION:
 SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:process ics file 555555
 DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-us:  \n
 TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
 TRANSP:OPAQUE
 END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first ical stream is just a simple event, without any attendee.
Your second ical stream is an iTIP message with METHOD CANCEL. iTIP CANCEL messages are meant to be used in the context of invitation (i.e. with ATTENDEE properties). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.5 . In your case the original event has not attendee and nor has the cancel.

You did not specify how those ics streams end up in your client ? If you are just importing them, I would try just removing the METHOD:CANCEL property in the second stream. The STATUS:CANCELLED should be enough.

Comment: i have tried removing METHOD:CANCEL property ,it creates new entry instead of cancelling the event

Comment: According to what i have understand cavcellation.ics UID should be same as event UID that need's to be cancel